# C# multi-user Tcp/Ip Chat application

Tags: c#, tcp, backgroundworker

I plan to write a C# application which can work as either a server or client. I implemented two WinForm. First one called ServerChat that on load call backgroundWorker

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    serverSocket.Start();
    try
    {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, clientSocket);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.UserState!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            frmChatClient = new frmChatClient("server", clientSocket);
            frmChatClient.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see when connection accepted, frmChatClient has shown which has its own backgroundWorker for the reading socket that passed in previous.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
           // in this line clientSocket is connected
            this.networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

           // this line throw exeotion
           networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, textbox1.MaxLength);

            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bytesFrom);

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0,dataFromClient);
           // break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
    }
}
```

After attempting to read or write I got the below error message

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

The connection was closed because no traffic was generated. If so, the socket will close the connection.

TcpClient is designed to be used for send/receive then close. It have no flexibility over its underlying socket. Instead of AcceptTcpClient, you can use AcceptSocket to get the accepted connection, then use TCP keep alive to let the connection to stay up. Or, if you want to use TcpClient, be sure to send keep alive packets.

On your protocol, you can provide an ALIVE packet with a small footprint payload just to inform server and client that the connection is still up and clear. Sending these types of packet instead of the standard TCP Keep Alive have pros and cons. But surely will make your client to remain connected.

Comment: thanx for helping me out i change all my TcpCLient and TCPListener to socket and when client is connected and server Accept Connection `Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);`  but still  throe the _An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host_ exeption

Comment: The code of your client respect the fact that a connection must receive/send or it will timeout?

Comment: in Client mod i send KeepAlive Message on from load and in read i send keepAlive  message after revive but  in server mode when it's stuck in Socket.Receive();

Comment: The send and receive must be continuosly. If not, the connection will be reset. Also, BackgroundWorker doesn't fit well for what are you doing. You cannot control very well the execution of the code because of the event driven model. It's good for heavy CPU operations, not for IO. Your flow can be broken at any point by the events queue.
It's better to use async methods of the socket classes and manage the async flow by yourself.

Comment: I write With Async from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example] and when connection excepted i going to show a from that going to NotResponding mod i think it's because of while(True)